# Insert new value in frozen field Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Table scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id uuid,
    date timestamp,
    components frozen <map <text, map<text, text>>>,
PRIMARY KEY (user_id));
```

As you see `components` is frozen field and I need to insert new value in it.

I tried this query:

`UPDATE kp.users SET components = components + {'new': {'key':'value'}} WHERE user_id='edf29208-adc5-4dc0-b6c4-b53b28cab95c';`

But got an error:

`Invalid operation (components = components + {'new': {'key': 'value'}}) for frozen collection column components`

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the field is frozen, you can't modify it - you need to update it as whole - even although it's a map, [it is one blob of data](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html).  If you want to update it, you need to implement logic on your side, but be beware of race conditions, like, when somebody will update the same value in parallel.